# Centimeter to feet and inches conversion

Tags: c++, data-conversion

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{
double cen, inch, feet;
double cen1, feet1;
feet1=cen1/2.54/12;
cin >> cen1;
printf("%.1f",cen1," centimeters is ",double(feet1)," feet ",(float(feet1)-int(feet1)))*12,"      `   inches.";
}
```

Right now, for some reason I keep on getting errors for the printf part for too many arguments and no use of the operand ",". My main problem is that I do not know how to set the stuff inside the printf so that I can control when decimals are taken off and how many are left remaining. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way but Please read a book / course on programming. As for the code `printf("%.1f centimeters is: %d feet %5.4f inches", cen1, int(feet1),(float(feet1)-int(feet1)))*12);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `printf` takes it's parameters.  The first parameter is the format string with the percent format codes, then followed by the parameters for the format codes.  It doesn't take a list of parameters and them combine them.

What you are looking for is:

```
printf("%.1f centimeters is %i feet %.1f inches", cen1, (int)feet1, (feet1-int(feet1))*12);
```

Comment: When i used your line of code, I got 333.3 centimeters is -2147483648 feet 6585518225804386000000000000000.0 inches. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @SeanChen use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: @SeanChen - I was missing a set of parentheses in my `printf` I've updated the answer.  But you also need to swap the lines `feet1=cen1/2.54/12;` and
`cin >> cen1;`.  You can't calculate a value before the user enters it.

Answer (score 0):

I use C++, however you may have your parenthesis in the wrong place. Try:

```
printf("%.1f",cen1," centimeters is ",double(feet1)," feet ",(float(feet1)-int(feet1))*12,"      `   inches.");
```

I am not sure if this will fix your problem for sure, however I believe it is an error that may be causing it.